# JSTL fmt timeZone does not work on server

Tags: java, jstl, simpledateformat

I am using the below code to convert a certain timestamp to GMT while rendering it on the UI. Although it works fine on my local it doesn't seem to work on server.

I am using Java 7.

Any idea what could be the reason.

```
createdon: <fmt:formatDate value="${message.createdOn}"  var="createdStr" timeZone="GMT" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"/> '<c:out value="${createdStr}"/>',
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work"? In what way doesn't it work? Show what you get and what you expect.

Comment: on my local i get the time as : 22-Sep-2015 07:13:19(gmt) and on server it shows 22-Sep-2015 12:43:19(IST)

Comment: Curious, because your pattern doesn't include a zone string, so it's weird that both output a zone name. Or is that just you attaching that by guessing? If so, your problem is likely upstream, i.e. where `message.createdOn` is assigned, in a Java handler(?). Assuming `message.createdOn` is a `java.util.Date` object, you can output the raw millis value using `${message.createdOn.time}`. I bet they are different.